# Can't find my folders after installing Google Sync and syncing with Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, google-sync

I installed Google's App Sync program to sync MS Outlook 2007 with a Google account. Having done this, I can't see my old Outlook e-mail folders (I'm pretty sure they were offline, on my PC). Is there any way I can adjust things to see those folders again, and to set up storage of old e-mails on my computer?

Comment: I found my old saved email (offline) folders by going here in Outlook:

Tools > Account Settings > Data Files > Add

Once there I just kept adding *.pst files until I found my old emails

Comment: Welcome to Super User! If you solve your problem, you should post what you did as an answer instead of a comment. That helps us with organization and gives you the possibility of earning more rep. I'll do it for you here, but I'll delete my answer if you add the answer yourself.

Comment: I tried.   I got a message telling that I could not do that because I didn't have enough reputation points or time in the system or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I found my old offline saved e-mail folders by going here in Outlook:

`Tools > Account Settings > Data Files > Add`

Once there, I just kept adding `*.pst` files until I found my old e-mails.